# underwater welding proceduce on a ship "approved by class": meaning?

Tags: phrase-meaning

From *[Taking the Plunge](http://evolution.skf.com/taking-the-plunge/)*, a text on an underwater welding effort to fix a ship's stabilizer.

> Subsea Global Solutions’ coded welder/divers used an industry-leading procedure **approved by class** to perform the underwater wet welding. Innovative solutions were employed, such as pad eyes designed to fold like a hinge, which helped to ensure that they didn’t clash against the fin box

What does "approved by class" mean here? Does it mean "approved by a [classification society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_society)" (a body engaged in establishing and maintaining standards in the maritime field)?

I have [one other quote](http://subseaworldnews.com/2014/09/12/smm-exclusive-subsea-global-solutions-looks-forward-to-bright-future/) from a representative of the same company:

> Probably one of the most significant elements that we were able to achieve this past month is the approval from **DNV GL** for underwater Class A wet weld.
>
> We’ve now been able to achieve permanent status on that weld from **Class** so what that means is we can weld certain materials, obviously certain types of steel on certain areas of the vessel and basically achieve the same metallurgical properties within the weld and within the base material as if that weld was done in a dry environment on the surface.

[DNV GL is a classification society](http://www.dnv.com/industry/maritime/servicessolutions/classification/), and the word **Class** seems to stand for "classification society" here. Could it be that the word **class** in the first passage also refers to a classification society?

I'm curious about that capitalized use of **class**. There's [a third quote](http://www.clevermarine.com/page_319128.html), it was [suggested](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=4&MessNum=316744&topic=13&l1=1&l2=2#topic) by a fellow translator at a forum:

> As aforementioned in our profile CMS Ltd started to provide ultrasonic thickness measurements (UTM) to vessel owners/managers in 2011 and obtained **Class approval** for it from Germanischer Lloyd, Buerau Veritas, Det Norske Veritas, RINA, Lloyds Register and the American Bureau of Shipping.

Would **Class approval** in this context mean "an approval by a classification society (or societies)"?

Comment: I'd say that the procedure is automatically approved (by whatever organization) for all things in class x, where x could be the type of ship, type of stabilizer or (this is my gut feeling) type of repair.

Comment: Right, it almost certainly means something like "approved within this class of work, as defined by some industry body"

Comment: @JoeBlow, I've added one other quote (from an interview given by a rep of SGS) in which the word "class" seems to refer to a particular classification society. I wonder if the meaning in my first quote is similar.

Comment: SGS have a WPS (Welding Procedure Specification) for a Class A underwater weld. This WPS had been approved by the classification society DnV. People often randomly capitalize words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, it probably means approved by (or in accordance with) each of the four classes (A, B, C, & D) of underwater welds defined by ANSI/AWS D3.6M:1999, Specification for Underwater Welding.

Comment: Thank you! But how could something be approved *by* a class? Approvals are given by professional bodies. A class is an abstract concept, having no power to approve anything (Class A, Class B, etc.) Or is it a specialized expression meaning "beloging to a class"? And why do you think that said procedure complies with the requirements of all the four classes? The text says nothing about that.

Comment: They have not chosen the clearest wording, but from context, I think that *"by"* means *"in accordance with"*

Comment: It isn't the class that's doing the approving "By" in this context is "according to" or "with respect to".  A similar meaning of "by" would be "sort a list of people by age".

Comment: Thank you both for the clarification! I'm also curious what do you think the capitalized "Class" stands for in my second quote.

Comment: @SimonB I agree with you.  The wording the the posted sentence is a little fuzzy, thus leading to questions.